# Fullcalendar V5 slotMinTime doesn't work for me

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I try to make slotMinTime and slotMaxTime on my Fullcalendar v5 but nothing is displayed. My Fullcalendar already start to 00:00:00 (default).
I try to follow this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMinTime but I can not

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar-holder');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                dateClick: function(info) {
                    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/booking/new/" + info.dateStr;
                },
                validRange: {
                    start: new Date(),
                    end: '2022-06-01'
                },
                defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
                slotMinTime: "07:00",
                allDaySlot: false,
                editable: true,
                duration: '01:00',
                eventSources: [
                    {
                        url: "{{ path('fc_load_events') }}",
                        method: "POST",
                        extraParams: {
                            filters: JSON.stringify({})
                        },
                        failure: () => {
                            // alert("There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!");
                        },
                    },
                ],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'timeGridWeek',
                },
                buttonText: {
                    timeGridWeek:'semaine',
                    today:'aujourd\'hui'
                },
                plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ], // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index
                timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
                locale: 'fr',
                eventDrop: function(drop) {
                    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000" + drop.event.url + "/edit/" + drop.event._instance.range.start + "/" + drop.event._instance.range.end;
                },
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using FullCalendar **v4**, not v5
[image: your Full Calendar reference]

[image: the source file]

Change your original code to from `slotMinTime` to `minTime` and `slotMaxTime` to `maxTime` and it'll work!

[image]

**Continue using your v4 files, and use**

```
slotMinTime: "07:00",
slotMaxTime: "18:00",
```

**or, upgrade your JS File references to v5, and use**

```
slotMinTime: "07:00",
slotMaxTime: "18:00",
```

Comment: thank you so much it work good and I have just I question, it's possible to hide or show the event according to the current user. For example, if Paul (current user)is login and he add a event (he see this event with his information (name, hours)), Jack (no current user)can see just for example a simple text like ("appointment already made")

Comment: Great to hear. Feel free to accept /  approve my answer. In my opinion, the easiest way to do that would be to pass the user id to the backend, and adjust the data that comes back if it is not the current user in the data. Either don't send other user's data, or adjust the title to just 'appointment already made'. You could do it in JavaScript, but you'd need to ship the userId in each line of data, do a comparison to a JavaScript held User Id, and then render the title's differently if there's no match.

Comment: ok i will try later but I put the code for this in ``eventSources`` Fullcalendar ? I don't know the javascript code

Comment: I succeeded to change title according to user but I use ``eventRender`` (Fullcalendar v4) I did not succeed to up in v5

Comment: Good to hear @ThomasDaSilva - If you have any different questions, you should maybe start fresh StackOverflow questions, and the community will endeavour to help

Answer (score 0):

A better way to use minTime for your method is

`scrollTime: '08:00'`

This way you don't lose all of the before time.